# Método que devolve o menor entre dois parâmetros não funciona

Tags: java, algoritmo

> Crie um método com dois parâmetros que retorna o menor de dois números passados como parâmetros

Quando eu não sei resolver, geralmente vou ver a resolução com explicação, mas acontece que dessa vez não tinha tradução para o inglês, apenas o original em suomi :/

Qual o motivo da função `smallest()` não retornar valor?

```
public class AdaLovelace {
             public static void main(String[] args) {
                  int result = smallest(1, 3);
                  
                  System.out.println(result);
            }
             
             public static int smallest(int n1, int n2){
                 if(n1 > n2){
                     return n2;
                 } else if(n2 > n1){
                     return n1;
                    }
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A função dá erro porque para o compilador há situação que pode não retornar um valor. Você tem uma condição que verifica se um deles é maior, depois verifica se o outro é maior, e quando for igual, faz o que? Dá erro. Não pode,

Acontece que só pode acontecer duas coisas aí se entrar na primeira condição deve retornar aquilo, se não não entrar então deve retornar a outra variável, só isso, não pode acontecer outra coisa, então simplificando o código e eliminando a verificação que não faz sentido porque já está garantido que é o oposto da outra, inclusive se for igual deve retornar qualquer dos números porque ambos são os menores, além de serem os maiores também, pra facilitar optei por retornar o segundo.

Escrevendo o código de forma mais simples, organizado e invertendo o sinal só para dar uma semântica mais adequada para o código porque ele pede para achar o menor e lendo o código parece que está pegando o maior (não está porque tem uma dupla inversão, inverte o operador e inverte quem é retornado), ficaria assim:

```
class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       System.out.println(smallest(1, 3));
    }
    public static int smallest(int n1, int n2) {
        if (n1 < n2) return n1;
        return n2;
    }
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/v8ccS7). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/ntlqszay-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Java/Algorithm/Smallest.java).